# How to create a route with multiple empty parameters in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

This is the format of my URLs:

```
controller/action/p1/p2/p3/
```

In the routing I have this rule:

```
url: 
    {controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/
defaults: 
    new { controller = "controller", action = "action", p1= "", p2= "", p3= "" }
```

In the controller I have:

```
action(p1 = "", p2 = "", p3 = "")
{
    ... 
}
```

I need to pass this URL `controller/action//p2/p3/` where `p1 = ""` the problem is that in the action method if `p1 = ""` it defaults to the value of `p2`. I mean `p1` takes now `p2`'s value.

How could I get this working? Maybe if I add more routes, or is there another workaround to accomplish passing in between empty parameters?

Comment: Are there any differnt patterns that p1, p2 or p3 follow so you can differentiate them? Perhaps p1 is numeric, and p2 is a string and maybe p3 begins with "category", etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what these parameters and values can be?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all p's are strings, the only way to differentiate separate routes is by the number of parameters. So in order to achieve the following mapping:

```
controller/action/p2/p3/
```

You can do it by adding the following mapping BEFORE the one with the three parameters:

```
url: 
    {controller}/{action}/{p2}/{p3}/
defaults: 
    new { controller = "controller", action = "action", p2= "", p3= "" }
```

However, playing with the same number of parameters and mapping them differently cannot be achieved without using QueryString parameters, e.g.:

```
controller/action?p1=""&p3=""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make variety of combinations with link of empty attributes, like here:

```
        var defaultObj = new { controller = "controller", action = "action", p1 = UrlParameter.Optional, p2 = UrlParameter.Optional, p3 = UrlParameter.Optional };

        string[] combinations = {
            "{controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}",
            "{controller}/{action}//{p2}/{p3}",
            "{controller}/{action}/{p1}//{p3}",
            "{controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}/",
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < combinations.Length; i++)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "route" + i.ToString(),
                url: combinations[i],
                defaults: defaultObj
            );
        }
```

Not best solution, but works for me.